# How to randomly choose an instance of a class and execute it's method?

Tags: java, multithreading, function, class, object

I have a function which writes to two buffers. The class is threaded in so that there are multiple writers to two buffers. In other words there are multiple producers on multiple shared buffers (Imagine two input belts).

The consumer thread needs to be able to randomly select instance1 or instance 2 of the buffer object to write to, and I'm not sure how to go about this in a manner which doesn't seem redundant (The function bodies and buffer objects are exactly the same, simply the object being written to will vary).

```
Pseudocode:

Buffer bufA;
Buffer bufB;

int randRes = random * 2 // Generate 1 or 0.

if randRes = 1 {

    if (bufA.tryInsert) {
    // Do things here
    } else {
    // Do other things here }

} else {

if (bufB.tryInsert) {
    // Do things here
    } else {
    // Do other things here }
}
```

Just seems somewhat redundant to me. As the functions if bodies themselves are somewhat big, and I may need to implement more than two buffers as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
final Buffer[] twoBuffers = {bufA, bufB};
final int randRes = random * 2; // Generate 1 or 0
final Buffer buffer = twoBuffers[random]; // Now you only have one buffer
if (buffer.tryInsert) {
    // Do things here
} else {
    // Do other things here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I like the approach taken here and the other mentioned. You've both given me something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an additional `Buffer` object which would be set according based on the `randRes` value.

```
Buffer bufA;
Buffer bufB;
Buffer toBeUsed; // Extra Buffer

int randRes = random % 2 // I think you need the modulo operator

if randRes = 1 {
    toBeUsed = bufA; // Use BufferA
} else {
    toBeUsed = bufB; // else use BufferB
}

if (toBeUsed .tryInsert) { // toBeUsed will be either A or B based on randRes value
    // Do things here
} else {
    // Do other things here
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, appreciated. I like the approach taken here and the other mentioned. You've both given me something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could an array and an interface (ie Runnable):

```
Runnable[] runnables = new Runnable[] {
    new Runnable() { ... },
    new Runnable() { ... },
    new Runnable() { ... }
};
Random random = new Random();

while (someCondition) {
   int randomInt = random.nextInt(runnables.length);
   runnables[randomInt].run();
}
```

Comment: Our brief dictates we cannot use any Java collection types other than array for this particular solution. Thanks however!

Comment: Ok, changed to use an array instead ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 Runnable is just a nice interface for a zero args method. If you need to pass some context, you could use a custom interface.

Comment: Overcomplicating a simple problem by introducing `Runnable` for no reason. Just select the `Buffer` from an array.

Comment: Hmm true. If he wants custom behaviour per buffer then the Runnables will help.

Comment: Yes, if he wants a different behavior, but I think he doesn't, this is why his code structure seems redundant to him ;)

Comment: Agreed. I've upvoted your solution but will leave my solution as food for thought ;)